# Nginx for accepting TCP connections on elastic beanstalk

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am have trouble uploading a custom nginx config to be used with a server accepting TCP connections on AWS elastic beanstalk. I am using docker and deploying a Go app. I have already enabled my load balancer to use Proxy Protocol but trying to change nginx to use proxy protocol is escaping me. I have researched tons online but to no avail. I have already tried creating bundling my .ebextensions/nginx.conf file containing

```
server {
  listen  80  proxy_protocol;
  real_ip_header  proxy_protocol;

  location / {
    proxy_http_version  1.1;
    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header  Connection  $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  Upgrade  $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_protocol_addr;
  }
}
```

but this doesn't work.  Could someone help me outline what I will need to accomplish? It would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you used, i am getting the same error in my node js app

Answer (score 0):

seems like your conf file syntax is missing the file location.
The correct syntax is:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf":
    content: |
      <nginx configuration file here>
```

I'd also recommend logging into the beanstalk instance using `eb ssh`, changing the file manually, restarting nginx (`service nginx restart`) and making sure your configuration file works as expected. Only then go on and create the `.ebextension` config file.

Comment: hey! thanks for getting back to me. upon further investigation I have decided to used another approach but thanks for taking the time!